# Diophantine equation $p^{2n}+2=3^m$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be a prime and let $m$, $n$ be positive integers.
Consider the equation

$$p^{2n}+2=3^m$$

It is easy to see that $(p,m,n)=(5,3,1)$ is a solution. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: The answer is no, but I don't know how to prove it. I just recall the general fact that $25$ is the only integer $n$ such that $n$ and $n+2$ are perfect powers.

Comment: $a^x-b^y=n$ is sometimes named Pillai's equation [OEIS A076427](https://oeis.org/A076427) as a generalization of [Catalan's conjecture (Mihăilescu's theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture#Generalization). See too the generalized [Tijdeman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman's_theorem).

Comment: @Rellek As far as I know, for arbitary powers only difference $1$ is actually solved.

Answer (score 2):

That the more general equation $x^2+2=y^n$ has only the solution corresponding to $x=5$ was proven $75$ years ago by Ljunggren. Such a result follows from applying the primitive divisor theorem of Bilu, Hanrot and Voutier.

Comment: Thank you Mike for pointing out the reference.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, but so far I've been able to show that $m$ has to be odd.

Because if $m$ is even, then $\frac{m}{2} \in \Bbb{N}$, and
$$p^{2n}+2=3^m$$
$$3^m-p^{2n} = 2$$
$$(3^\frac{m}{2}-p^n)(3^\frac{m}{2}+p^n) = 2$$
Since $\frac{m}{2}$ is a positive whole number, and $3^\frac{m}{2}+p^n > 3^\frac{m}{2}-p^n$, this can only happen when
$$\text{I.}\  3^\frac{m}{2}-p^n = 1 \ \ \text{  and } \\ \text{II.}\ 
 3^\frac{m}{2}+p^n = 2.$$
From the second equation:
$$p^n = 2 - 3^\frac{m}{2}$$
Putting this into the first equation:
$$3^{\frac{m}{2}}-2+3^{\frac{m}{2}}=1$$
$$2 \times 3^{\frac{m}{2}} = 3$$
Since the left side is even, and the right side is odd, this equation has no solution, so $m$ has to be odd.

Comment: You should have written $3^m - p^{2n} = 2$.

Comment: Thank you. This actually made almost the entire calculation different, but fortunately it still works. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Since p is prime. Then m must be odd anyway.